# document is listing to click, how to trigger event on a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

As i need to listen events form dynamically created elements , i was suggested to listen event on document level so i created a global click Event Listener, and start listening to desired element as following

```
$j(document).on("click",function(e) { 

      if (  $j(e.toElement).parent().is( $menu )   ) {
            // click on menu
      }

      if (  $j(e.toElement).parent().is( $tabs )   ) {
            // click on tabs
      }


})
```

but now i want to trigger a click for say on menu, but when i do

```
$menu.trigger("click");
```

but its not working . Need help

Comment: Please add a working example with a service like jsfiddle or jsbin to make it easier to debug your code

Comment: Cannot you just delegate event passing as parameter  `selector` string to `on()` method?

Comment: `As i need to listen events form dynamically created elements , i was suggested to listen event on document level` And why don't you just try to use relevant event delegation as specified in DOC or other hundred duplicate topics?

Comment: actually im new to jquery, so dont know much about it, oky i will search relevant event delegation ,thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why someone would use it but that would do the trick:

```
var event = jQuery.Event('click');
event.toElement = $menu.children().first();
$(document).trigger(event);
```

No instead, just delegate event:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selectorFor$menu', function(){
  /**/
});
$(document).on('click', 'selectorFor$tab', function(){
  /**/
});
```

Comment: perfectly working,but sir can you please tell me that why this is so bad to listen event on a document level

Answer (score -1):

I mean there are a lot of unknowns here, but my advice to make sure that you're importing jQuery correctly:

Then make sure you understand how the selectors work: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

For example, if your menu as `id="menu"`, then it will look something like this:

```
<div id="menu">This is the menu</div>
```

And, your jQuery selector will look like this:

```
$('#menu').click( function() { alert("you clicked me.") } )
```

jsfiddle is great to use for examples, see the example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/e15oynhc/